# Raspberry Pi Webcam Reset

Tags: webcam

I'm making a timelapse video with a Raspberry Pi and a Microsoft Lifecam HD-5000 webcam.  Everything is working great except that I have to reset the camera every morning or I end up with totally white images.  I think the light sensor gets stuck open overnight.

My image grabbing script runs every two minutes and uses fswebcam to take the pic.  I'm using `luvcview` to reset the camera in the morning, which isn't very elegant because it's not a command-line tool.  It works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way.  I've also tried using `sudo rmmod uvcvideo` and then `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try `uvcdynctrl`. Not sure if it can reset the camera, but it can save and load controls to/from a file.

Comment: `man luvcview` to see options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's what I figured out:

When I open Luvcview in first thing in the morning, the image is very overexposed for a few seconds, then corrects itself. Apparently opening the stream kicks off the camera's native autofocus and autoexposure features.  After some digging, I discovered that fswebcam can grab an image averaged across a number of frames.

So, I waited until mid-morning when it was bright outside, and manually took the first image of the day with one frame.  Very overexposed.  Tried again with 5 frames, and it looks great.  Back to one frame, still looks great.

**SUMMARY:** The video stream from the camera has to run for longer than a single frame for it to reset itself.  I will run the first grab of every hour with a 5-frame exposure to keep the images looking good as the light changes throughout the day.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I used two options from fswebcam, one that takes pictures after a delay and one that skips a certain number of frames. This is the stem of the command (then I add some date dependent file name)

```
fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 2560x1440 -S 10 -F 10 -D 1
```

Check the manual for -S and -D and play a bit with them. See what works for you.

Hope it helps!